# Term for additional payments from your employer

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word (or, if no single word exists, a short expression) that includes anything that is not your base salary (e.g. overtime, bonuses, sale commisions). If possible, I would like it to not require any additional context (so "Hey, I got my x today!" could be understood, even if it sounded awkward).

Comment: base salary plus additional emoluments. Or: plus additional amounts.

Comment: if you're willing to co-opt some french/spanish, _extra-salarial payments_ could work. (really [salarial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/salarial) should be a word in English imo)

Comment: @rossih I'm afraid that is not English. There is no adjective in English for the noun salary. Salary plus additional payments or amounts.

Comment: @Lambie yup, that's why its a comment not an answer :)

Comment: The concept "money that is not part of your base salary" exists but it has no single word.  People say *I got my OT (overtime) today* or *I got my bonus today* not *I got my generic-word-for-money-not-base-salary*.

Comment: If you say you received overtime pay, a bonus, or a sales commission, it will be understood that those payments are not part of your regular (base) pay/salary. If you think a word or phrase covering all of them is necessary, you should add some rationale or context for using them.

Comment: There is simply nothing that means "non-base-salary payment of any kind whatsoever" except perhaps **the moolah I've been waiting for**  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply say **extra pay** (or, even more colloquially, **extra money**).

This assumes that it's paid to you by an employer, it's not part of your base salary, and it doesn't matter in what way the money gets to you.